# Passing map (matrix) to class C++

Tags: c++, class, matrix

I wanted to know how can I create new matrixes with different width & height
by passing values to class.

for example:

```
  myClass map1;

  map1.matrix[width][height] = { "###","###"}
```

( this is not the corrcet code but im looking for something like that )

Comment: I think you're confused about what a matrix is, and what a map is... I think you should go read a good book   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I mean the map of the game using matrix ( console game ) ( for example lvl 1 have some walls and a goal and created with 20x20 matrix, like that )

Comment: Where is myClass defined?

Comment: #include <iostream>

#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H
#pragma once

class Console
{
public:

 int x = 1;
 int y = 1;
 Console();
 ~Console();
 void Move(int V, int H);
};

extern char map[6][16];
extern char map2[6][16];
#endif
( i used something like that but i want to make a map for every levels with only giving its length , width , and map characters by passing them to class from main class )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html). It allows you to create multidimensional arrays with contents of arbitrary content type. I have used it (the boost::multi_array_ref part to be more specific) and it works pretty nice. An important feature is the ability to create array [views](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_views) (and slices based on views).